# How can I get attrdict module working in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to execute the following example:

```
from attrdict import AttrDict

a = AttrDict({'foo': 'bar'})
print(a.foo)
```

but I got this error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\collections\__init__.py)`

How can I solve it? I feel it is like bug.
And when I looked inside the file I noticed some problems in it:

`C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\collections\__init__.py`:

[image]

Comment: AttrDict is not being supported anymore. A good alternative is [attridict](https://pypi.org/project/attridict/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [AttrDict](https://github.com/bcj/AttrDict) project was broken by a change in the move to Python 3.10 but since it was marked as inactive in 2019, this hasn't been fixed.

I found a [discussion that seems to indicate that it will be reopened](https://github.com/wallento/wavedrompy/issues/32) but that doesn't seem to have happened. Looks like we'll have to find alternatives,  check out [`addict`](https://pypi.org/project/addict/).

Answer (score 1):

You can monkeypatch the collections module near the start of your app before the module is imported elsewhere.

```py
# Monkey patch collections
import collections
import collections.abc
for type_name in collections.abc.__all__:
    setattr(collections, type_name, getattr(collections.abc, type_name))
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been searching for a suitable alternative but have been unable to find one. I created a fork of the AttrDict project - [attrdictionary](https://pypi.org/project/attrdictionary/). I have performed code refactoring and have thoroughly tested all aspects of the project. Additionally, I have ensured that the forked project remains fully compatible with Python versions ranging from 3.8 up to the latest release, Python 3.11. If you need an alternative, you can use this package.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to AttrDict is [attridict](https://pypi.org/project/attridict/).
With attridict, your code will look like

```
import attridict
a = attridict({'foo': 'bar'})
print(a.foo) #'bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

If all  you need is that, you can create your own attrdict in few lines of code:

```
from collections import UserDict

class AttrDict(UserDict):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self.__getitem__(key)
    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        if key == "data":
            return super().__setattr__(key, value)
        return self.__setitem__(key, value)
```

And you are done.
(it just won't work for an attribute named "data", because that is used internally by UserDict - if you really need that, it would require a workaroud with a few extra lines)